# Trying to Calculate Month over Month percentage increase/decrease

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sum, calculated-field

I am trying to calculate Month over Month % change on data rows. For example my current output is:

```
DataDate |LocationId|Payment|MoM [Current placeholder column in script]             
12-1-2013|LocationA |$5.00  |      
1-1-2014 |LocationA |$10.00 |    
2-1-2014 |LocationA |$100.00|   
12-1-2013|LocationB |$50.00 |    
1-1-2014 |LocationB |$25.00 |    
2-1-2014 |LocationB |$50.00 |
```

I am pasting the results into Excel and then calculating the MoM by using the following formula:
    ((CurrentDataDate Payment/PreviousDataDate Payment)-1)]

I can not figure out where to even begin trying to accomplish this so I cant provide any coding from what i have tried...I have read about and attempted a correlated scalar query used to calculate running totals and tried to alter it to accomplish this...no dice...I tried with a Join and a subquery but i will admit my subquery abilities are less than adequate.

The code used to call this info is:

```
Declare @BeginDate as DateTime
Declare @EndDate as DateTime    
Set @BeginDate = '12-01-2013'
Set @EndDate = '02-01-2014'

Select DataDate,LocationId,Payment,0 as MoM
From dbo.mytableview
Where DataMonth between @BeginDate and @EndDate
```

Desired output is:

```
DataDate |LocationId|Payment|MoM              
12-1-2013|LocationA |$5.00  |      
1-1-2014 |LocationA |$10.00 |1.0  [or 100%]  
2-1-2014 |LocationA |$100.00|9.0  [or 900%] 
12-1-2013|LocationB |$50.00 |    
1-1-2014 |LocationB |$25.00 |-.50 [or -50%]  
2-1-2014 |LocationB |$50.00 |1.0  [or 100%]
```

I am using Microsoft SQLServer 2008 R2. I also have/and can use the 2012 version if that is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on SQL Server 2012:

```
with x as (
select datadate, locationid, payment,
    lag(payment) over(partition by locationid order by datadate) as prev_payment
from table
)
select *, (payment/prev_payment)-1
from x
```

Comment: @JohnBustos _"I also have/and can use the 2012 version if that is needed."_ :)

Comment: you sir are a gentleman and a scholar....works perfectly and I appreciate it greatly!

Comment: I have co-workers that still use 2008 R2 so if others have an answer for that, it will help me as well....

Answer (score 0):

Although dean's solution is better, I just wanted to also post a solution for people that don't have SQL Server 2012 for completeness' sake (and since I had already started on it before dean posted his).

This can be accomplished using Common Table Expressions and the `Row_Number()` function:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY locationid ORDER BY datadate) AS RN, datadate, locationid, payment
FROM table
)

SELECT 
    CTE2.*, 
    (CTE2.payment / CTE1.payment) - 1 AS MOM
FROM
    CTE AS CTE1 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    CTE AS CTE2
ON
    CTE1.RN = CTE2.RN-1
AND
    CTE2.locationid = CTE1.locationid 
ORDER BY
    locationid
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, works on earlier versions:

```
select *, (t2.payment/t1.payment)-1
from #t t1
left join #t t2 on datediff(month, t1.datadate, t2.datadate)=1
and t1.locationid = t2.locationid
```

However, this self-join solutions generally don't perform well with larger sets of data, and a cursor solution is preferred in such cases.